# How to get contacts from Titanium Backup on Windows PC - without restoring on a phone?

Tags: contacts, data-recovery, titanium-backup

I made a backup of my phone using Titanium Backup, including the contacts.

How can i open this contacts backup on a Windows PC so I can see all contacts data?
I would like to restore them manually (or add the missing info to existing contacts).

I would like to avoid restoring this backup on a mobile phone.

Comment: A very similar question: [How can I manually extract my contacts from a backup image of Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32767/how-can-i-manually-extract-my-contacts-from-a-backup-image-of-android)

Comment: See https://thydzik.com/export-android-contacts-contacts2-db-to-vcard-vcf-on-windows/